# I am getting invalid if load dropdown data in ngOnit - Angular

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have Mutiple dropdown field with validation. I am populating the dropdown data in onInit, am getting data in dropdown but while submitting the form its showing error because of form control validation.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="addNoticeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">
        <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-4 p-xl-3">
            <label for="companyRole">Company Role<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
            <p-multiSelect [disabled]="isViewDisable" placeholder="Select an option" formControlName="companyRole"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedCompanyRole" [options]="companyRoleOptions" optionLabel="name" optionValue="code"
                appMultiSelection (onChange)="getSelectedRole(companyRole)"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && p.companyRole.errors?.error }"></p-multiSelect>
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && p.companyRole.errors && p.companyRole.errors?.error">
                {{p.companyRole.errors?.error}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TS:**

this.companyRoleOptions.forEach((item) => this.selectedCompanyRole.push(item.code));
this.getSelectedRole(this.selectedCompanyRole);

I attached screen shot for reference:
[image]
[image]

Comment: please show the `addNoticeForm` initializing code in ts

Comment: @Bharath: Thanks for your reply, I resolved this issue by using patchvalue

Answer (score 0):

Try this by stackblitz it will work.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-dropdown-reactive-forms

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I resolved this issue by using patchvalue